# Running several Grails / Jetty instances on the same server and same port, but with different host names

Tags: grails, groovy, jetty, ports, cometd

I would like to run several Grails applications, powered by Jetty (but I could change the server to Tomcat if needed, however I need the Continuations API for CometD features) on the same server. They all need to be on port 80, but have different domain names (myfirstsite.com, mysecondsite.com)

Is there a way to run several apps this way ?

Comment: This excellent blog just brought its answer :  http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/grails-goodness-add-additional-web.html

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to use Apache HTTPD virtual hosts, using mod_proxy to connect to Jetty or Tomcat.

Comment: Actually mod_proxy seems not to be a good idea for me because I use Cometd, and httpd uses a thread-per-request model, see here http://cometd.org/node/81

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be complicated to [run different webapps on different virtual hosts on Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Virtual+hosts#Virtualhosts-Configuringdifferentwebappsfordifferentvirtualhosts).

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try that one.